# Efficacy of bounties by reward amount

Tags: discussion, bounty, statistics

Is there any data available on how often bountied questions receive answers? Can we stratify by bounty amount, to see if we're actually 'getting more bang for our buck' when we bounty higher amounts?

If the answer above is yes, can we get more fine-grain data? Can we plot additional views gained against bounty offered and look at the slope to see how many additional views we get per additional bounty point? What about bounty offered versus additional upvotes gained? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) queries available in some related posts, such as: [How effective are bounties?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20155) (on [math.meta.se]) or [Probability of getting an answer by bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200414) (on [meta.se])? Probably you might find some other similar posts. (You'll probably want to run those queries for MO - just a reminder to switch the site when running them.)

Comment: I always felt that bounties on MO were a bit redundant. It's fine if you want to draw attention to it, but MO for the most part is not very gamified. I don't think that a lot of people here are seriously working towards higher reputation, so a bounty serves mostly as a payment for higher visibility rather than a dangled carrot. (That is my personal opinion from the last decade or so, it is based on anecdotal evidence, and has nothing to back it up.)

Comment: Some bounties not offered with the intention to reward an existing answer rather than attract new answers. In such cases, we cannot say that the goal of the bounty wasn't fulfilled if no new answer is added. (I have added [a few comments in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/how-effective-are-bounties). We can discuss some related things there - if we want to avoid having a long comment thread.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I think newer users find setting and reaping the bounties more important. My own first reputation came from answering a bountied question and then from getting its bounty.